# AVI Resource Playing

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a Form "TForm1" having one "TAnimate1". I have one AVI Resource as File Name "Animate 01.avi" with Resource Identifier "AVI" and one "Animated Cursor" as File Name "Cursor 01.ani" with Resource Identifier "8".

I wish to play "Animate 01.avi" on "FormCreate" event and set default cursor as "8".

I'm using "Delphi XE2".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load an avi in a [TAnimate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/ComCtrls.TAnimate) from a resource, you must use the [`ResHandle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TAnimate.ResHandle) and  [`ResId`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/ComCtrls.TAnimate.ResId) or [`ResName`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/ComCtrls.TAnimate.ResName) properties.

if you have the id of the resource use a code like this

```
  Animate1.ResHandle:=HInstance;
  Animate1.ResId    :=2;//this is the id of the resource
```

if you have the name of the resource

```
  Animate1.ResHandle:=HInstance;
  Animate1.Resame :='MyAvi';//this is the name of the resource
```

to load a cursor from a resource you must use the [`LoadCursor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function

```
Screen.Cursors[NIndex] := LoadCursor(HInstance, '8');//or if you are using a number instead an string LoadCursor(HInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(8))
```

Comment: Please download and see my Project File and tell me where to recify. Please please help me. Download link "http://hotfile.com/dl/137675080/34f701f/KoushikHalder01.7z.html"